# jquery show() method not showing all the elements after first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert a row from GUI and when i click on add , it calls the `show()` method to display the row , i submit the form , row is added to DB , all good , reset() function is called which hides the new row , after that if i again call the `show()` method to add a row , it shows only some parts of row , i mean some textboxes are not shown

[image: First time Adding (calling <code>show()</code>)]

[image: Calling <code>show()</code> 2nd time or other]

When i call show 2nd time **without loading the page again** then only this happens , if i load the jsp page again , the issue goes

code for show :

```
  $('.newrow').show();
```

`newrow` class has all the elements

images are in order 
1 calling first time (all works well)
2 calling 2nd time (All fields dont show)

code :

```
 <tbody class="newrow" hidden>
 <tr bgcolor="6699cc">
 <td class="td" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"></td>
 <td disabled></td>
<td>
<select class="env" style="width:100px">            
<option value="DEV">DEV</option>
<option value="DEV-VPMO">DEV-VPMO</option>
</select>   
</td>

<td>
<select class="region" style="width:100px">

 <option value="JACKSON">JACKSON</option>
<option value="CHARLOTTE">CHARLOTTE</option>
<option value="PLEASANT-HILL">PLEASANT-HILL</option>

</select>  

</td>

<td class="td" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="text" class="url"></td> 
<td class="td" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="text" class="rnode"></td>
<td class="td" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="text" class="user" style="width:60px"></td>
<td class="td" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="text" class="password" style="width:70px"></td> 
<td class="td" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="checkbox" class="ed-up" name="1"></td>
<td><button class="cancel">X</button></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please provide sample code. `$('.newrow').show()` will always show elected elements

Comment: Post some `html` too please..

Comment: Is the `reset` function just hiding the elements or removing them?are you sure the elements you expect on 2nd time do have that class?

Comment: @techie_28 yes .. i am just calling show() and hide() methods on that class

Comment: I m saying that is that class still on the element on the second time or is it being removed somewhere by the code?